# How to run cyclic background process in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some methods that works with API of third party app. To do it on button click is no problem, but it should be permanent process.

How to run them background? And how to pause the cycle for make some other works with same API and resume the cycle after the job is done.

Now I read about ActiveJob, but its has time dependences only...

**UPDATE**

I've tried to make it with `whenever` and `sidekiq`, task runs, but it do nothing. Where to look for logs I can't understand.

```
**schedule.rb**

every 1.minute do
  runner "UpdateWorker.perform_async"
end

**update_worker.rb**

    class UpdateWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
      include CommonMods

      def perform
        logger.info "Things are happening."
        logger.debug "Here's some info: #{hash.inspect}"
        myMethod
      end
      def myMethod
            ....
            ....
            ....
      end
   end
```

It's not exactly what I need, but better then nothing.  Can somebody explain me with examples?

**UPDATE 2** After manipulating with code it's absolutely necessary to restart **sidekiq** . With this problem is solved, but I'm not sure that this is the best way.

Comment: You need [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to scheduling your cron jobs(task) and for background process [sidekiq gem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) here is [rails cast for background process](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

Comment: You can define your output directly into `config/schedule.rb` with `set :output, "log/cron.log"` for example

Answer (score 1):

You can define a job which enqueues itself:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(*args)
    # Do something unless some flag is raised
  ensure
    self.class.set(wait: 1.hour).perform_later(*args)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries to schedule jobs on a regular basis. For example you could use to [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) to run a job every minute.

If you want to pause it for some time, you could set a flag somewhere (Redis/database/file) and skip execution as long it is detected.

On a somewhat related note: don't use [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq). It was really great but it's not maintained anymore and has incompatibilities to current Sidekiq versions.

Comment: but I don't know how much time it'll take to do the job. for this reason I can't to say that I need the job must be executed every 1 or 5 minutes. I can say execute the job after finish the job. It's cycle in other words.

Comment: You could just enqueue a new job as a last step in the current job.

Answer (score 0):

Just enqueue next execution in `ensure` section after job completes after checking some flag that indicates that it should.

Also i recommend adding some delay there so that you don't end up with dead loop on some error inside job

Answer (score 0):

I dont know ActiveJobs, but I can recommend the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to create cron (periodic background) jobs. Basically you end up writing a `rake` tasks. Like this:

```
desc 'send digest email'
 task send_digest_email: :environment do
  # ... set options if any
  UserMailer.digest_email_update(options).deliver!
end
```

I never added  a rake task to itself but  for repeated processing you could do somehow like this (from  answers to this specific question)

```
Rake::Task["send_digest_email"].execute
```